# Compiling with NDK gives error for successfully included header files

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

My app.cpp:

```
#include "app.h"


#include <EGL/egl.h>
#include <EGL/eglext.h>

void
Java_com_geek_hello_FilterStack_nativeEglSetFenceAndWait(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz) {
  EGLDisplay display = eglGetCurrentDisplay();

  // Create a egl fence and wait for egl to return it.
  // Additional reference on egl fence sync can be found in:
  // http://www.khronos.org/registry/vg/extensions/KHR/EGL_KHR_fence_sync.txt
  EGLSyncKHR fence = eglCreateSyncKHR(display, EGL_SYNC_FENCE_KHR, NULL);
  if (fence == EGL_NO_SYNC_KHR) {
    return;
  }
  ...
```

When I run ndk-build, it fails finding methods present in egl.h and .so is not created. Here's the log:

```
app.cpp:31:72: error: 'eglCreateSyncKHR' was not declared in this scope
```

followed by all KHR methods that belong to

Here's Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

#LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DEGL_EGLEXT_PROTOTYPES
LOCAL_CFLAGS = -Wno-psabi

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := app.cpp

#LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libcutils libEGL

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional

LOCAL_MODULE := libapp
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -landroid -lEGL -lGLESv2

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add:

```
#define EGL_EGLEXT_PROTOTYPES
```

before your `#include` lines (well, specifically before including `EGL/eglext.h`).

Also (and it looks like you're already doing this), you need to be building against at least API 14, since that's the first API level exposing this function in the public API.

EDIT: or just uncomment the line in your Android.mk that reads:

```
#LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DEGL_EGLEXT_PROTOTYPES
```

Answer (score 2):

Try following all the steps in:

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Android_GLUT_Wrapper

From the log that you provided, the build can't find the EGL library, so I think you need the line

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog -landroid -lEGL -lGLESv2
```

in your Android.mk. And make sure your Application.mk includes:

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_PLATFORM := android-9
```

Comment: I added that. Here's the new error.
In file included from /Users/geek/code/app/jni/app.h:20:0,
                 from /Users/geek/code/app/jni/app.cpp:17:
/android-14/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:592:13: note: the mangling of 'va_list' has changed in GCC 4.4
/Users/geek/code/app/jni/jni_egl_fence.cpp: In function 'void Java_com_android_gallery3d_photoeditor_FilterStack_nativeEglSetFenceAndWait(JNIEnv*, jobject)':
/Users/geek/code/app/jni/app.cpp:31:72: error: 'eglCreateSyncKHR' was not declared in this scope

Comment: What the hell this means? I've no idea about c++. "the mangling of 'va_list' has changed in GCC 4.4"

Comment: That just looks like a warning. The error is "'eglCreateSyncKHR' was not declared in this scope." You need to include #include <EGL/egl.h>
#include <EGL/eglext.h> wherever you're using EGL functions

Comment: For more information about the warning see https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-ndk/mrk5dDqWioM

Comment: See my app.cpp, they are included

Comment: va_list error is gone with your link. now the error is: app.cpp:31:72: error: 'eglCreateSyncKHR' was not declared in this scope

Comment: Was the error from your first comment the entire error? All I can go by is what the error is saying "error: 'eglCreateSyncKHR' was not declared in this scope". Try changing your Application.mk to include the line "APP_PLATFORM := android-9" because the EGL headers are only in android-9 and above.

Comment: error at line 31 is followed by errors at following lines, all of them are KHR related. I'm already building with SDK 14 (minSdk version is 14 in manifest). I still tried that, didn't change anything.

Comment: My last suggestion is to move #include <EGL/egl.h>
#include <EGL/eglext.h> into app.h

Answer (score 0):

i think you should follow this steps for more understanding
[steps](http://psrdotcom.blogspot.in/2011/12/android-ndk-jni-windows-xp7-with-3264.html)

and before make bulid pls make sour

- project path untill jni folde > and  ndk path untill ndk-build 
  ex D:\New_Wok_2\Firstndk\jni>c:\android-ndk-r8\ndk-build
  and clean your project